# Connect digital antenna to MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

Does anybody know if I can connect my MacBook Pro via a cable to the box on the wall that is connected to a digital antenna.

I'm renting a property and don't want to buy a TV I just want to watch free view via laptop. I do have a broadband connection....would that be easier.

Answer (score 1):

I not sure that you can directly connect your MacBook to a Real Tv antenna, but you have this solution : http://www.ebay.com/bhp/usb-tv-antenna